# Atualizar elementos dentro de um for usando jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Olá,

Estou iniciando na programação web, e minha pergunta acredito que seja simples,
hoje tenho uma determinada pagina que contém um forech para exibir de for dinamica uma lista de um pedido

```
   <tbody>
                  <?php $i =0; foreach($itens as $item): ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <?=  $item->item_id ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?= $item->getNomeProduto($item->item_prod) ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php  if($pedMagazine->maga_tolerancia==1){?>
                          <input type="number" name="item_vlruni" id="item_vlruni" value="<?= $item->item_vlruni?>" disabled/>
                          <input type="hidden" name="item_vlruni[]" value="<?= $item->item_vlruni?>" />
                          <?php }else echo  $item->item_vlruni  ;?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php  if($pedMagazine->maga_tolerancia==1){?>
                          <input type="number" name="item_qtd" id="item_qtd" min="<?= round($item->item_qtd*(1-($pedMagazine->maga_toleranciaperc/100)))?>" max="<?= round($item->item_qtd*(1+($pedMagazine->maga_toleranciaperc/100)))?>" onchange='sePedidoItem.somar();' step="1"
                          value="<?= $item->item_qtd?>" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="item_id[]" value="<?= $item->item_id?>" />
                          <?php }else {echo $item->item_qtd; }?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php  if($pedMagazine->maga_tolerancia==1){?>
                          <input type="number" name="item_vlrtot[]" id="item_vlrtot" value="<?= $item->item_vlrtot?>" disabled/>
                          <input type="hidden" name="item_vlrtot[]" value="<?= $item->item_vlrtot?>" />
                          <?php }else echo $item->item_vlrtot; ?>
                      </td>
                      <?php //$subTotal+=$item->item_vlrtot ;?>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $i++; endforeach;  ?>
                </tbody>
```

estou usando jquery para atualizar os campos de vlrtotal (valor total) que seria a multiplicação vlruni com qtd, minha função;

```
   somar: function () {        


     $("#vlrTot").val($("#qtd").val()*$("#vlrUni").val());
      $("#item_vlrtot[]").val($("#item_qtd").val()*$("#item_vlruni").val());},
```

Só que como estou usando um foreach ele esta atualizando apenas o primeiro campo e o resto não atualiza.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer para ele atualizar todos os campos independente do tamanho do for?

Comment: Se está iniciando com web, fica a sugestão de não misturar PHP, Javascript e jQuery. Seria bom dominar separadamente cada uma das coisas. E depois de aprender, usar jQuery somente quando realmente justificar. Quase sempre JS puro resolve (e muita coisa só no PHP já se resolve, aliás).

Comment: hm, poderia dar uma dica de como resolver essa questão, talvez utilizando somente php. ponto é que quero que atualize o campo sem precisar atualizar a pagina

Comment: No caso são 2 coisas separadas. Se é só exibição, o PHP basta. Se a pessoa vai alterar dinamicamente, e o total acompanhar, é caso para o JS. Seria bom além do código postado (que ja ajuda), explicar qual é o resultado pretendido com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valeu pessoal, consegui realizar o que eu queria na verdade o codigo ficou assim;

```
  <tbody>
                  <?php  foreach($itens as $key=>$item): ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <?=  $item->item_id ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?= $item->getNomeProduto($item->item_prod) ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php  if($pedMagazine->maga_tolerancia==1){?>
                          <input type="number" name="item_vlruni" id="item_vlruni<?= $key ?>" value="<?= $item->item_vlruni?>" disabled/>
                          <input type="hidden" name="item_vlruni[]" value="<?= $item->item_vlruni?>" />
                          <?php }else echo  $item->item_vlruni  ;?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php  if($pedMagazine->maga_tolerancia==1){?>
                          <input type="number" name="item_qtd" id="item_qtd<?= $key ?>" min="<?= round($item->item_qtd*(1-($pedMagazine->maga_toleranciaperc/100)))?>" max="<?= round($item->item_qtd*(1+($pedMagazine->maga_toleranciaperc/100)))?>" onchange='sePedidoItem.somar(<?= $key ?>);' step="1"
                          value="<?= $item->item_qtd?>" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="item_id[]" value="<?= $item->item_qtd?>" />
                          <?php }else {echo $item->item_qtd; }?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php  if($pedMagazine->maga_tolerancia==1){?>
                          <input type="number" name="item_vlrtot[]" id="item_vlrtot<?= $key ?>" value="<?= $item->item_vlrtot?>" disabled/>
                          <input type="hidden" name="item_vlrtot[]" value="<?= $item->item_vlrtot?>" />
                          <?php }else echo $item->item_vlrtot; ?>
                      </td>
                      <?php $subTotal+=$item->item_vlrtd ;?>
                    </tr>
                    <?php  endforeach;  ?>
                </tbody>
```

E no jquery ficou assim

```
 somar: function (i) {

// soma para os itens editados no pedido
$('#vlrTot').val($('#qtd').val() * $('#vlrUni').val())

// logica para atualizar campos na tela confirmar 
var antigo = $('#item_vlrtot' + i).val()
// atualiza o campo vlrtot
$('#item_vlrtot' + i).val($('#item_qtd' + i).val() * $('#item_vlruni' + i).val())
var soma = $('#item_vlrtot' + i).val() - antigo
soma = soma + parseInt(document.getElementById('subTotal').textContent)
// atualiza valortotal
document.getElementById('subTotal').textContent = soma  },
```

Notem que no meu html alterei meu foreach "oreach($itens as $key=>$item)" e adicionei para receber um valor na função somar do jquery "somar: function (i) {" no caso o "i", assim no onchange eu chamo a função junto com a key "onchange='sePedidoItem.somar( $key "com as tag php");'" e consigo realizar o calculo dinamicamente.

Answer (score 0):

Ciro, vejo que você tem uma tabela com inputs para valor unitario, quantidade e valor total.

O primeiro problema que vejo, é a repetição dos `id`s nos elementos. como os `id`s devem ser unicos, considere mudar a estrategia utilizada para nomear os mesmos, ou até mesmo remover o `id` (no caso acima me parece que isto não deve afetar a sua aplicação).

outro ponto, não vejo a necessidade de haver um `input[type='hidden']` e `input[type='number']` simultaneamente. acredito que o `input[type='hidden']` seja interresante apenas se o `maga_tolerancia == 1`, ou melhor, use `input[type='number']` para tudo e apenas coloque `readonly='readonly'` nos inputs.

por fim, adicione uma `class` a linha, podemos fazer isto para utilizar a linha (`tr`) como escopo para as suas operações, assim como classes para os `input`s.

```
<tbody>
  <?php $i =0; foreach($itens as $item): ?>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>
      <?=  $item->item_id ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?= $item->getNomeProduto($item->item_prod) ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="item_vlruni[]" class="item_vlruni" 
            value="<?= $item->item_vlruni?>" <?php if($pedMagazine->maga_tolerancia!=1){?>readonly='readonly' disabled='disabled'<?php }?>/>
    </td>
    <td>      
      <input type="number" name="item_qtd[]" class="item_qtd" step="1" 
            min="<?= round($item->item_qtd*(1-($pedMagazine->maga_toleranciaperc/100)))?>" 
            max="<?= round($item->item_qtd*(1+($pedMagazine->maga_toleranciaperc/100)))?>" 
            value="<?= $item->item_qtd?>" <?php if($pedMagazine->maga_tolerancia!=1){?>readonly='readonly' disabled='disabled'<?php }?> />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="item_vlrtot[]" class="item_vlrtot" 
            value="<?= $item->item_vlrtot?>" <?php if($pedMagazine->maga_tolerancia!=1){?>readonly='readonly' disabled='disabled'<?php }?>/>
    </td>
    <?php //$subTotal+=$item->item_vlrtot ;?>
  </tr>
  <?php $i++; endforeach;  ?>
</tbody>
```

note que não sou um programador `PHP`, então pode haver algum erro basico na sugestão acima.

agora vamos para o `JavaScript`.:

```
var itens = $('.item');
itens.each(function (indice) {
  var item = $(this);
  var item_vlruni = $(".item_vlruni", item);
  var item_qtd = $(".item_qtd", item);
  var item_vlrtot = $(".item_vlrtot", item);

  var onInput = function (event) {
    var vlruni = parseFloat(item_vlruni.val());
    var qtd = parseFloat(item_qtd.val());
    item_vlrtot.val(vlruni * qtd);
  }

  item_vlruni.on("input", onInput);
  item_qtd.on("input", onInput);  
});
```

Note que adicionei a `class='item'` à `tr`, fiz isto para que fosse possivel selecionar todas as linhas, depois eu percorro cada linha selecionando apenas os inputs dentro das mesmas, para tal eu passo a linha como segundo argumento no seletor, como no exemplo `$(".item_vlruni", item)`, por fim faço o `bind` do evento `input`, que é onde será realizado o calculo.